# How to write this query string in better way?

Tags: javascript, refactoring, query-string

I see an line of our code base in JavaScript to construct a query string:

```
    var queryParameters = "imagePath=" + encodeURIComponent(_image.source) + "&saveMode=" + saveMode + "&pageFolderId=" + pageFolderId + "&id=" + pageId + "&parent=" + parent;
    queryParameters += "&quality=" + sQuality.value + "&commands=" + commandQueue.Serialize();
```

is there a better way to write this?

Comment: What's the problem with this line? Are you looking for something more easily readable?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using jQuery, you could just use an object representing your query string options:

```
var queryParameters = jQuery.param({
    imagePath: _image.source,
    saveMode: saveMode,
    pageFolderId: pageId,
    // ...
});
```

jQuery will automatically encode the query string values, so you don't need to call `encodeURIComponent` on `_image.source`. See for more info: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.param/

Answer (score 1):

You could use line breaks:

```
var queryParameters = "imagePath=" + encodeURIComponent(_image.source) 
    + "&saveMode=" + saveMode 
    + "&pageFolderId=" + pageFolderId 
    + "&id=" + pageId 
    + "&parent=" + parent
    + "&quality=" + sQuality.value 
    + "&commands=" + commandQueue.Serialize();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put all of the data into an array and then execute a join. Generally join of an array is faster then concatenation but if you don't build this string multiple times shouldn't make a difference.

```
var arr = [];
arr[1] = "item1";
arr[2] = "item2";
arr[3] = "item3";
var result = arr.join('');
```

Writing it like this improves readability and debugging too. You can comment one parameter very easy.

Comment: Joining an array was faster once upon a time, but JavaScript engine optimizations seem to have changed all that. http://jsperf.com/string-concatenation-plus-vs-join.

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. But there are alot of other factors, such as what browser do you use and what version. You have to see what browser does the majority of users have and optimize for it.

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
function qSerialize(obj){
  var q = [];
  for (var l in obj) {
   if (obj.hasOwnProperty(l)){
     q.push(l+'='+obj[l]);
   }
  }
  return q.join('&');
}

var qParamStr = qSerialize( 
 {
  imagePath: encodeURIComponent(_image.source),
  saveMode: saveMode,
  pageFolderId: pageFolderId,
  id: pageId,
  parent: parent,
  quality: sQuality.value,
  commands: commandQueue.Serialize()
 }
);
```